# Optimizing python loop & function

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, optimization

I'm looking for some optimization on the below code.
I've measured the time of various parts of it, which prompted me to few optimization areas:

1. `scores.append(...))` seems to be taking a lot of time, compared to just running the function for the result. Any way to improve the efficiency of collecting the results? At the and I want to calculate average for each of the run (MC). 184s/272s - 70% seems really a lot?
2. `for i in range(0,100000):` - since I'm basically running the same function x-times, maybe I can try to increase the efficiency there somehow? Also, maybe some parallelization is an option?
3. `match_simulation` function, I probably cannot vectorize/parellelize - because each loop is dependent on the results of previous ones. But I've found a couple of areas that improved the perfomance, e.g. by moving stats calculation before the big loop (it's the same), which improved a lot. Anything else anyone sees there?
4. `resolve_action` function basically adds values to score dictionary based on random and stats. It imputs current `score` as parameter and utilizes a lot of `score[xxx] += 1` - I'm wondering if that is optimal or could be improved?

If anyone sees anything else, I'd be glad for a suggestions! Basically I have the same "function", dummy-written in excel file, where I can refresh the randoms to get the results and it is faster, which means there must be a lot wrong with the python implementation atm ;)

A bit of stats on **execution times**. Using https://github.com/amerghaida/jackedCodeTimerPY as timer:

```
label                 min           max           mean       total    run count
-----------------  ------  ------------  -------------  ----------  -----------
Total              272.84  272.84        272.84         272.84                1
Loop                 0       0.25997       0.000271895  271.895         1000000
match_simulation     0       0.25797       8.817e-05     88.17          1000000
Action loop          0       0.25797       6.96475e-05   69.6475        1000000
resolveAction        0       0.0290003     2.77846e-06   41.6769       15000000
pullBack             0       0.00300026    6.83808e-07   10.2571       15000000
Shuffling            0       0.00199914    9.55838e-06    9.55838       1000000
Initial asignment    0       0.00299644    4.98002e-06    4.98002       1000000
scoreCalc            0       0.0149989     8.25524e-07    0.825524      1000000
```

Thanks!

**Code:**

```
def match_simulation(teamHStat, teamAStat, stats, JTimer):
    JTimer.start('match_simulation')
    
    JTimer.start('Initial asignment')
    act_stats = stats
    
    score = {"H_wins" : 0, "H_draws" : 0, "H_looses" : 0, 'H_goals' : 0, 'A_goals' : 0
            , "H_rolled" : 0, "A_rolled" : 0, "H_not_rolled" : 0, "A_not_rolled" : 0
            , "H_l" : 0, "H_r" : 0, "H_c" : 0, "H_sp" : 0
            , "H_lg" : 0, "H_rg" : 0, "H_cg" : 0, "H_spg" : 0
            , "H_ca_l" : 0, "H_ca_r" : 0, "H_ca_c": 0, "H_ca_sp": 0             
            , "H_ca_lg" : 0, "H_ca_rg" : 0, "H_ca_cg": 0, "H_ca_spg": 0
            , "A_l" : 0, "A_r" : 0, "A_c" : 0, "A_sp" : 0
            , "A_lg" : 0, "A_rg" : 0, "A_cg" : 0, "A_spg" : 0
            , "A_ca_l" : 0, "A_ca_r" : 0, "A_ca_c": 0, "A_ca_sp": 0
            , "A_ca_lg" : 0, "A_ca_rg" : 0, "A_ca_cg": 0, "A_ca_spg": 0
            , "H_common" : 0, "A_common" : 0, "H_own" : 0, "A_own" : 0
            , 'H_miss' : 0, "A_miss" : 0, 'H_ca_miss' : 0, "A_ca_miss" : 0
            , "H_PDIM": 0, "A_PDIM" : 0, "H_PNF" : 0, "A_PNF" : 0, "H_PNF_miss" : 0, "A_PNF_miss" : 0
            , "H_ca_not_rolled" : 0, "A_ca_not_rolled" : 0, "H_ca_rolled" : 0, "A_ca_rolled" : 0}
    
    action_types = ['H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'Common', 'Common', 'Common', 'Common', 'Common']
    JTimer.stop('Initial asignment')
    JTimer.start('Shuffling')
    shuffle(action_types)
    JTimer.stop('Shuffling')
        
    JTimer.start('Action loop')
    for action_type in action_types:
        prev_score = score
        JTimer.start('resolveAction')
        score = resolveAction(act_stats, action_type, score)
        JTimer.stop('resolveAction')
        
        JTimer.start('pullBack')
        if(score['H_goals'] > prev_score['H_goals'] or score['A_goals'] > prev_score['A_goals']):
            act_stats = stats_calculation(
                pullBack(score['H_goals'], score['A_goals'], teamHStat)
                , pullBack(score['A_goals'], score['H_goals'], teamAStat))
        JTimer.stop('pullBack')
    JTimer.stop('Action loop')
            
    JTimer.start('scoreCalc')
    if(score['H_goals'] > score['A_goals']):
        score['H_wins'] += 1
    elif score['H_goals'] == score['A_goals']:
        score['H_draws'] += 1
    else:
        score['H_looses'] += 1
    JTimer.stop('scoreCalc')
        
    JTimer.stop('match_simulation')
    return score
```

```
JTimer = JackedTiming()
JTimer.start('Total')
scores = []
stats = stats_calculation(teamHstats.iloc[0], teamAstats.iloc[0])
for i in range(0,100000):
    JTimer.start('Loop')
    scores.append(match_simulation(teamHstats.iloc[0], teamAstats.iloc[0], stats, JTimer))
    JTimer.stop('Loop')    
JTimer.stop('Total')

print(JTimer.report())
```

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Answer (score 0):

While testing, I've noticed that

```
scores.append(match_simulation(teamHstats.iloc[0], teamAstats.iloc[0], stats, JTimer))
```

is very inefficient due to `teamHstats.iloc[0]`. So instead of doing that, I've changed to `teamHstat = teamHstats.iloc[0]` and `match_simulation(teamHstat, ...)` which improved speed significantly.

Interesting to see.